# Any way to add custom data to a Kinesis Data Stream using Amazon Kinesis Agent on Linux?

Tags: redhat, amazon-kinesis

Looking to use Amazon's Kinesis Agent on Red Hat Linux to upload data to a Kinesis Data Stream.

I've been able to successfully upload files using the Kinesis Agent to a Kinesis data stream.

What I'm also looking to do is add additional custom envelope data to each record being written to the Kinesis data stream by the Kinesis Agent.   Things like an incrementing sequence number, or a continually changing time stamp etc.  To be clear, this is not data already in the file being uploaded.  This would be data that would be added to each record in the file as the data is being written to the Kinesis stream via the Kinesis agent.

I see that Amazon's Kinesis Agent for Windows supports Sink Declarations that allow adding additional custom information into a Kinesis Data Stream.

Not finding anywhere online if there's a way to add additional custom data to the records being written to a Kinesis data stream using Amazon's Kinesis Agent for Linux.

I tried searching online and not finding any references to this whatsoever.   Just looking for documentation if it exists?

Comment: maybe additional tags to improve findability, e.g. Linux? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a couple of days, I've concluded that you cannot add additional metadata to a Kinesis Stream using Kinesis Agent for Linux at this time.  The only way to do this using Amazon's Kinesis Agent for Linux would be to modify the open-source Kinesis Agent Source Code available on GitHub.

Note, There is an addition to the open source Kinesis Agent to add EC2 metadata to a Kinesis Stream, but I'm looking to add data beyond the EC2 metadata.

The windows version of Kinesis Agent does support adding additional meta data to a Kinesis Stream via Sink Declarations, but unfortunately, I need a solution to work on Linux.

Would love for someone to come along and tell me there is a way to do this, but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: This looks like valuable additional information, complementing yet not answering your own question, hence that would fit perfectly **inside your question** post.